# How to solve the "cold start" problem in computer vision based deep learning models?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, yolo

By “Cold Start” I mean that often computer vision models for object detection or semantic segmentation require about 5000 images per class. So if an idea if floated within the company for e.g. we want to use object detection to count the number of wood logs when the truck is dispatched and then use the same app to count the number that is received.

So now the challenge is that you have only a few images of woods logs on a truck but to train any model you need thousands, so what do practitioners typically do for these prototypes?

Because at this stage it is not clear what model to try? It is also not very feasible to ask business to invest in collecting thousands of images of logs and label them?

That is why I am calling this “Cold Start”. How do you start?

What I have looked into is Conditional GANs, Pix-2-Pix but I am trying to understand the recommended method on how to start when you have very few images per object class.

I expect that when I drop a few images in a folder and call this library I end up getting a lot more images per class so I can then start my prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

Note that asking for software libraries is *specifically* off-topic here.

No, there is no magic solution: if your data set doesn't have enough information in its images to train a hand-crafted model, no amount of software will change that fact.  However, the first approach is to challenge that "fact": how do you *know* that you don't have enough images?  What happened when you used what you have to train a model?  You will train for more epochs before the model converges, but you should be able to achieve far better than random accuracy by training a comparable quantity of iterations.

I seriously doubt that you'll need to collect and label thousands of images: you have a very restricted paradigm, photos of log trucks taken from an vantage point you control.  Training a model to count non-overlapping near-circles will take much less differentiation than, say, distinguishing motor vehicles from postal boxes.

Experiment with the basic models you have at hand -- you already have much more of the solution than you realize.  If your data set is too small, go out the yard with a digital camera and get twice as many, three times, whatever you need.  Flip the images left-right to get more input.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks. The issue just to be clear is that I don't have a model yet. What I have is the business sent me this scenario saying can we use AI to count the number of logs loaded on the truck. So I just have 2-3 images. Now I needed to try to see what sort of accuracy can I get and even suggest them what's the best way. That is why I wondered if there was something that can take my 2-3 images and then create thousands so I can train a baseline model. This happens many times where the business will send a few images and ask is this possible.

Comment: Ah -- so you're a remote consultant, rather than an employee with ready access to the shipping yard?  This type of situation is common?  Yes, you have a bit of relationship communication here.  There's a notable difference between 3 photos with a total of 26 log ends (quite similar in visual structure), and 3 photos each showing a single non-homogeneous item.

Comment: Also, a model that's only partially trained on your 3 photos (and 3 mirror images) can be used to label additional photos with a great degree of accuracy.  You should take less time if you correct those by hand, than if you start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer learning solves the problem you are describing as "Cold Start". Basically you can import the weights obtained after training using a big and open dataset and just fine-tune them using the smaller dataset you already have. Data augmentation, freezing some of the layers, etc may help improving the results of a fine-tuned model.